# QGraphicsBlurEffect degrades the performance?

Tags: c++, performance, qt, qframe

I am developing GUI in Qt5 with animation on `QWidget`s and `QFrame`s, I have set blur effect on `QFrame` as I set `QFrame` as a parent of few of my `QWidget`s and I set `QPropertyAnimation` on `QWidget` which increases and decreases its size depending upon action. If I remove blur effect set on `QFrame` animation works smoothly but when I set it it doesn't. So my question is, is `QGraphicsEffects` degrades the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blur effect has some overhead depending on the blur radius, the widget it is applied to and the blur hints. You can set the blur hint to `QGraphicsBlurEffect::PerformanceHint` :

```
effect->setBlurHints(QGraphicsBlurEffect::PerformanceHint);
```

From the Qt documentation about `QGraphicsBlurEffect::PerformanceHint` :

> Indicates that rendering performance is the most important factor, at
>   the potential cost of lower quality.

So if you set this hint, the performance would be much better.